# Bootstrap Navbar: при открытии меню, часть шапки оказывается под ним

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, bootstrap4

Хочу разместить ссылку с правой стороны и в обычной и в мобильной версии, но при этом, чтобы эта ссылка была зафиксирована с правой стороны всегда: и на компьютере и на мобильном. Все как бы работает, подумал я, но есть одна проблема.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот так выглядит Navbar в мобильной версии (именно сверху, на нижнее вертикальное меню не обращайте внимания). Видим, что справа ссылка размещена. Теперь нажимаю кнопку раскрытия меню с остальными ссылками:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видите, проблема в том, размещенная мною ссылка справа тоже выпадает, да и вообще, словно вся эта часть navbar'а сползает вниз, судя по тому, что даже navbar-brand сместился. Код выглядит так:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-sm bg-light border-bottom">
    <button class="d-md-none navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-content" aria-controls="navbar-content" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand mx-md-0 mx-sm-auto">Laravel</a>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-content">
        <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-left">
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Item 1</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Item</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Пробовал поменять местами div с коллапсом и ul со ссылкой справа - тогда в мобильной версии все как я и хочу, а в обычной ссылка получается не справа, а слева, сразу после brand. Что делаю не так?

Comment: Какую именно ссылку? где она должна стоять? что не получается? слова "эта ссылка", не дают понятия. что именно вы хотите сделать?

Comment: Справа только одна ссылка с именем "Item", разве не видно?

Comment: и что с ней нужно сделать?

Comment: Нужно, чтобы она всегда была справа, даже на маленьких дисплеях. Проблема в том, что при раскрытии меню (в маленьких дисплеях) эта ссылка тоже уходит вниз. Посмотрите на скрины. На втором скрине видно, что происходит при раскрытии меню

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поместите выпадающее меню в конец блока. Меню не спозиционированно абсолютно, и поэтому смещает вашу ссылку:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-sm bg-light border-bottom">
  <button class="d-md-none navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-content" aria-controls="navbar-content" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

  <a href="#" class="navbar-brand mx-md-0 mx-sm-auto">Laravel</a>

  <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-right order-md-3">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="#" class="nav-link">Item</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-content">
    <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-left">
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Item 1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Я в конце своего вопроса написал: "Пробовал поменять местами div с коллапсом и ul со ссылкой справа - тогда в мобильной версии все как я и хочу, а в обычной ссылка получается не справа, а слева, сразу после brand. "
Собсна, так у меня и получилось, как вы предлагаете (я про код), но на диспелях побольше ссылка не справа находится, а сразу после brand

Comment: добавьте к ul .order-md-3

Comment: а ну, sm-, lg- можете прописать еще

Comment: Воо. То, что нужно. Спасибо большое! :)